# Apache Flink: How are failures handled in the DataSet API?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have two questions regarding the failure handling in Flink's DataSet API:

1. Why isn't the checkpointing mechanism mentioned in documentation of the DataSet API?
2. How are failures handled in the DataSet API, e.g., for `reduce` or `reduceGroup` transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink handles failures differently for streaming and batch programs.

For streaming programs, the input stream is unbound such that it is in general not possible or not feasible to replay the complete input in case of a failure. Instead Flink consistently checkpoints the state of operators and user functions and restores the state in case of a failure.

For batch programs, Flink recomputes intermediate results, which were lost due to failures, by reading the necessary input data and evaluating the relevant transformations again. This is true for all transformations, including `reduce` and `reduceGroup`.

Comment: Let's take a simple example of a word count operation in flink. If one of the task executor got killed then how will flink cope up from this behaviour? There is no way for it to subtract the word count obtained for the words from this failed task executor in the past.